# MS Access not working for multi user

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, multiple-users

I have a DB I created as a sort of real time virtual client check in log. It would be stored on an intranet network drive. In theory, a greeter can send client information back to be picked up by another worker. This is done through a series of forms, tables, and queries. When I test it myself on my own machine, opening both the greeter and reception forms I can enter information on the greeter, click the action button to send it to the table, where a timered query(held in a hidden form opened with an AutoExec macro) picks up the current record, and then displays it on the reception form. Everything works perfectly. The only problem is, when I try to test it on multiple computers, the greeter can send info back, it appears on the table, but the reception form never populates. Any ideas where the disconnect might be?

*edit* I have decided I want to do away with the hidden initialize form, so I've re-organized the code as follows. It still works when I do it myself on one computer, but opening the reception form on another computer it still fails to populate.

Reception 1

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()

If gClientID > gNextClientID Then
gblnRNC = True
Else: gblnRNC = False
End If

If gblnRNC = True And gblnRec1Free = True Then
gRec1CL = gNextClientID
MsgBox "There is a new client to be seen.", vbSystemModal, "New Client  Warning"
Me.RecordSource = "RecClientIDNum"
End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the database split?  Does the user having trouble have the correct permissions for the folder where the database is stored?

Comment: The database is not split. One of the functions I wanted to incorporate was the ability to export a copy of the days logs and then clear the tables so they would be ready for the next day, but one of them includes an attachment field, and the easiest way I found to refresh that table was to delete the attachment column and re-add it, but if I split the database my code to do so gives me a 3611 error. I don't think permissions are the issue, I even signed myself into two different computers and get the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried the database on another computer without trying it on multiple machines? So, run the same tests that you do on your computer on another machine, does that still have issues or work correctly? Also, what method are you using to populate the form in question (`reception form`)?

Comment: @Jiggles32 I'll have to wait until someone is gone to lunch to try it on another computer, we have a pretty busy office and barely enough computers to go around as it is, but I've posted the code that populates the reception form to my original question.

Comment: Works correctly from another computer too.

Comment: Could the issue be with having multiple copies of the initialize form running? It currently opens for each user that opens the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So forgive my noob question, I sorta jumped into programming procedures without fully understanding how Access works. I declared global variables but didn't realize they were only global within the scope of the local session running on a particular machine.

Moved the variables that establish the interactions between the various forms to a table and everything works perfectly.